# Recovering Xcode project from Snapshot

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just messed up my whole project trying to refactor it to include ARC. Now I've been trying to revert from the snapshot arc refactoring created, but it made an even bigger mess. What can I do in this situation? Is there a way to grab the snapshot clean instead of trying to use it as a reference point to modify the project to the previous state?

Comment: Cant really help you here, but to tell you that after being bitten many times by that 'feature' of xCode, i ended up doing 3 things. 1) turn Snapshot off 2) rely on time machine for local mishaps like this, 3) put my projects on a git remote repo. And finally found a replacement for xCode. best of luck with your issue.

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised with your answer. Still hoping some ray of light might come from somewhere :)  Cheers!

Comment: The only ray of light is insight after the fact: use source control (ie builtin git support of Xcode) to be able to safely revert back to any previously committed state. In addition, perform regular Time Machine backups to ensure that you can always revert the source controlled project to its previous state if anything ever happens that you can not back out of (such as deleting the .git folder).

Comment: Thanks Steffen (@LearnCocos2D) :). After a whole day of a mixture of old SVN assets and files from the snapshot I finally recovered my project to it's current state. Thanks guys for the insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found online how to recover a Snapshot by going into the organizer/projects, selecting the snapshot I want to recover, then clicking on "Export Snapshot" at the bottom. After some patchwork I finally got my project to the state it was before the chaos! Thanks everyone who replied! I hope this is helpful to anyone else. Cheers!

Comment: Great. When you can, click the checkmark to the left of your answer to accept it so that others know that this has been solved. :)

Comment: Ah I'm such a StackOverflow newb that they won't let me do it for 24 hours after I answered my own question, unfortunately. But I will asap. Thanks!